# Formalism for unambiguous context-sensitive languages?

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, parsers

I know that there are some languages that are unambiguous but not context-free (this is a good fact). Is there any kind of formalism for describing unambiguous context-sensitive languages? Even better yet, is there a parsing algorithm for unambiguous context-sensitive languages?

Comment: Beyond the obvious -- unambiguous grammars, standard parsing algorithm for context-sensitive grammars -- what are you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I found something close enough to what I want. They're [unambiguous boolean grammars](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0890540108000631) and they're both unambiguous and strictly more powerful than context-free grammars. Other people may find this useful, so I decided to share it.